# Attraction between electromagnet and a permanent magnet - at which point is the force the strongest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

You have an air-core inductor with current applied, so that the magnet in the picture will be attracted to it. At what position will the force between the two be the strongest and at which the weakest?

Is the force when the magnet is 1cm away from the coil weaker or stronger then when it's 1cm inside the coil?

At what position will the magnetic force align and the magnet stop (excluding the inertia force and other non-magnetic forces involved). If the coil is much longer than the magnet will it stop in the middle of the coil?

Thanks :) This isn't a physics homework or something, I'm trying to find out how to best design a linear magnetic actuator and which position of the magnet allows for the strongest force.

[image]